# how to reduce size of the package using ng-packagr

Tags: angular5, ng-packagr

I am using ng-packagr to generate a library for my angular components ( angular CLI project), I felt the size is big. how can we reduce the size of the package by using ng-packagr

Observation: it is generating esm5,esm2015,fesm5,fesm5 folder which is having more size, are these are all really required or one folder is sufficient.

i am using the following versions

"ng-packagr": "^3.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "~5.2.9",

Thanks,
Srinivas.

Answer (score 1):

As said here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview#heading=h.k0mh3o8u5hx

This are package layouts, which allows the support of the following usage-scenarios and environments:

[image]